Blender 4.3.0 Linux CLI, symbol lookup error: blender: undefined symbol: vkGetDeviceBufferMemoryRequirements
I am seeing this error when running blender --version command:
blender: symbol lookup error: blender: undefined symbol: vkGetDeviceBufferMemoryRequirements

I only see this error for blender 4.3.0. For example, blender 4.2.3 works fine:
Blender 4.2.3 LTS
        build date: 2024-10-15
        build time: 23:33:05
        build commit date: 2024-10-14
        build commit time: 15:20
        build hash: 0e22e4fcea03
        build branch: blender-v4.2-release
        build platform: Linux
        build type: Release
        build c flags:  -Wall -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wno-stringop-overread -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wnonnull -Wabsolute-value -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable  -march=x86-64-v2 -std=gnu11 -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off
        build c++ flags:  -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wcomma-subscript -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wno-suggest-override -Wuninitialized -Wno-stringop-overread -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations  -march=x86-64-v2 -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off
        build link flags:  -Wl,--version-script='/home/blender/git/blender-v420/blender.git/source/creator/symbols_unix.map'
        build system: CMake

I also tried bunch of other blender versions, they all work fine.
My OS is: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa). My CPU is AMD EPYC 7532 32-Core Processor. GPU is NVIDIA RTX A2000

We can't help with possible bugs as there are no Blender developers here. Suggest you report it using Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.

Incidentally that command works fine under Windows 10.
